# How do I put an image onto the surface of a mesh?

Tags: texturing, materials

How do i get the .tga image on the right onto the mesh on the left?

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make an object use your image texture, try creating a new material under your "Material Properties" tab, then choosing your image.

[image]

As long as you have unwrapped your Object, your image should be applied to the object. If it looks stretched, choppy or just tiled in a way you don't like; this is a reference to a [node structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktrNS.jpg) I use for my meshes.

But if you are planning on using images as like a background or even a wall, there is one option for you that I use pretty consistently and is built right into blender!

First thing you will want to do is go to your User Preferences under File -> User Preferences. next, go to the Add-On Tab in the middle and search for an Add-On called Images as Planes. Once you find it, click the little check box and close the User Interface window. Now, you can press Shift - A to add a new mesh as you normally would and instead of choosing a mesh, go to the bottom and select "Images as Planes". This will bring up a new window where you can choose your image file, and once it has been imported it will show up in your world as a plane.